# Unable to draw lines on windows form chart control

Tags: c#, charts, windows-forms-designer

Using a chart control on a windows form in C#, with visual studio 2010 IDE.

I'm creating a chart that plots random points.  Once points are generated, I run a loop for each point in the chart, looking at all the other point coordinates.  Inside that loop, I calculate the distance from the parent point to it's neighbor.  If the distance is <= some distance that I specify, I want a line to be drawn showing a connection between the two.  Problem I'm having though is actually drawing that line.  Further more, I then need to find a way to walk the shortest path in that chart.

So this is really two questions:
1. How do I draw the lines on the chart? (current dilemma)
2. How do I walk the graph to find the shortest path?

Here is a snipper of some code I'm using to accomplish this, along with the current error:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    public void createNodes(int x, int y, int Nodes, int dgNodes)
    {
        Random rdn = new Random();

        for (int i = 0; i < (Nodes - dgNodes); i++)
        {
            chtGraph.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY
                        (rdn.Next(x), rdn.Next(y));
        }

        for (int i = 0; i <= dgNodes - 1; i++)
        {
            chtGraph.Series["Series2"].Points.AddXY
                        (rdn.Next(x), rdn.Next(y));
        }
    }

    public void buildGraph(int x, int y, int Nodes, int dgNodes)
    {
        //set the min/max axis on the chart
        chtGraph.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Maximum = x;
        chtGraph.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Minimum = 0;
        chtGraph.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Maximum = y;
        chtGraph.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Minimum = 0;
        chtGraph.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.Interval = x / 10;
        chtGraph.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.Interval = y / 10;

        chtGraph.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisX.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;
        chtGraph.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].AxisY.MajorGrid.Enabled = false;

        //build all the nodes
        createNodes(x, y, Nodes, dgNodes);
    }

    public void drawEdges(int intNumNodes, int intTransPower)
    {

        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 1);
        Graphics g = chtGraph.CreateGraphics();

        Point[] pts = new Point[intNumNodes];
        int i = 0;

        //Gather all the data generator data points into a point array
        foreach (DataPoint p in chtGraph.Series[0].Points)
        {
            Point point = new Point((int)p.XValue, (int)p.YValues[0]);
            pts[i] = point;
            i++;
        }

        //Gather all the non data generator into the same point array
        foreach (DataPoint p in chtGraph.Series[1].Points)
        {
            Point point = new Point((int)p.XValue, (int)p.YValues[0]);
            pts[i] = point;
            i++;
        }

        //loop through all the data points
        foreach (Point p in pts)
        {
            //examine all the other data points for each data point visited
            for (int j = 0; j < pts.Length; j++)
            {

                //if the distance from the parent node (p) to the neighbor node is less than the transmit power, then draw a line
                if (Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow((p.X - pts[j].X), 2) + Math.Pow((p.Y - pts[j].Y), 2)) <= intTransPower)
                {
                    //gr.DrawLine(pen, p, pts[j]);
                    //gr.Graphics.DrawLine(pen, p.X, p.Y, pts[j].X, pts[j].Y);

                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void btnExecute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (txtDG.Text == "" || txtNodes.Text == "" || txtStorage.Text == "" || txtTransPower.Text == ""
            || txtXAxis.Text == "" || txtXAxis.Text == "")
        {
            lblError.Text = "Please enter in all inputs!";
            lblError.Visible = true;
            return;
        }
        //create variables for use through program

        int intTransPower = Convert.ToInt32(txtTransPower.Text);
        int intXAxis = Convert.ToInt32(txtXAxis.Text);
        int intYAxis = Convert.ToInt32(txtYAxis.Text);
        int intNum_DG = Convert.ToInt32(txtDG.Text);
        int intNumNodes = Convert.ToInt32(txtNodes.Text);
        int intStorage = Convert.ToInt32(txtStorage.Text);

        lblError.Visible = false;
        lblError.Text = "";

        if (txtDG.Text == "" || txtNodes.Text == "" || txtStorage.Text == "" || txtTransPower.Text == "" 
            || txtXAxis.Text == "" || txtXAxis.Text == "")
        {
        lblError.Text = "Please enter in all inputs!";
        lblError.Visible = true;}

        chtGraph.Series["Series1"].Points.Clear();
        chtGraph.Series["Series2"].Points.Clear();

        buildGraph(intXAxis, intYAxis, intNumNodes, intNum_DG);

        drawEdges(intNumNodes, intTransPower);
    }

}
```

Error: Error    1   The type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartGraphics' has no constructors defined

Comment: That's the job of a chart control.  If you want to paint anything extra then write an event handler for its PostPaint event.  It e.ChartGraphics member gives you the Graphics object you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used event described in comment in the question.